# Counting dough...pick up doughs

Tags: singular-vs-plural, countability

You have flakes or small pieces of different colors of dough. Do you pluralize these and say, "pick up all these or dough**s**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dough is considered **uncountable** like sugar, water, advice and money.

If you need to make it **countable** you need to introduce a *unit*. This may be a precise unit like *teaspoons* of sugar or *buckets* of water or abstract terms like *some* advice or *all* money.

So in yor example, you can either say:

> pick up *all / all the* dough

or

> pick up *all pieces/crumbs/flakes* of dough

Answer (score 0):

[cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dough) labels dough as [ C or U ], which means Countable or Uncountable.

You could use dough as Uncountable

> pick up 3 pieces of dough

You could also use dough as Countable

> pick up 3 doughs

Comment: But the latter would imply different kinds or batches of dough (like pastry, yeast and phyllo dough, for example or three batches of the same, e.g. because the mixer can not make enough in one go), not the crumbs the OP  is asking about.